# Prevent textarea with only <br> from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am trying to build a comment section that allows instant preview on the front end.

Everything worked fine except the behavior after submitting the comment.

In my code, I trigger the submission of the comment when the user press the Enter key in the textarea, then clear the textarea by resetting the value.

However, even after I disabled the default behavior of the enter key by declaring e.preventDefault(), a new line is still inserted when enter is pressed repeatedly.

Also, even after I check the length of the value of the textarea before submitting, my code accept comment with only 
 / '\n' as valid content and hence the user will be able to submit 'empty' comment if they press enter in the textarea multiple times...

Please help, I cannot think of a solution and I am considering to add a post button where the user has to manually click it to submit...

My code on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ve0gLab/2/

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#comment-input').keydown(function(e){
        var commentContent = $(this).val()
        if (e.which == 13) {e.preventDefault()}
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault()
            if (commentContent.length != 0) {
            $('#comment').append(commentContent)
            $(this).val('') 
        }

        else {
            alert('Comment is empty')} /*This line is not working properly*/
        }       
    })
})
```

Comment: replace the `}` on that line with a `;` and try again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may address your issue:

```
if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13){ 
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ve0gLab/4/)**

Comment: Wonderful solution! It even prevented the unwanted behavior where the cursor went down a row when a new comment is submitted! Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

Try change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#comment-input').keydown(function(e){
        var commentContent = $(this).val();
        if (e.which == 13) {
            if (commentContent.trim()){
                $('#container').append("<p>"+commentContent+"</p>");
                $(this).val('');
            }
            else {alert('Area is empty');}
        }        
    })
})
```

notice the ".trim()" which is a javascript string method.

you can try in the jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/xdxqwLof/

Comment: This is also a great solution, thank you for helping. I wasn't aware that JS has this useful built in function. Thanks!